# Can we exclude a specific file system in File-system consistent snapshot backup in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I would like to exclude one of the file system from Azure Linux Snapshot backup. Is there way ?

I'm using Operating System:- RHEL 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

1. To skip the mount point, update /etc/azure/vmbackup.conf as below.

[SnapshotThread]
MountsToSkip = /mnt/abc

2. To exclude disks from Snapshot backup, use "az backup protection" CLI command